# Unit test memory leak from useEffect setInterval

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, memory-leaks, setinterval, clearinterval

I am attempting to unit test my countdown timer, and I want to run an individual test for the day, hour and minute; however, when I run my tests I am receiving the pesky memory leak issue, and I'm not sure how to fix it after I've tried the usual method of returning from the `useEffect`, clearing the interval.

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

**Component**

```
import { addSeconds, intervalToDuration } from 'date-fns';

const MyComponent = () => {
    let now = new Date(); // Will be mocked in the test
    const endDate = new Date('2022-12-25'); // Arbitrary date
    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(intervalToDuration(now, endDate));
    const {days, hours, minutes, seconds} = timeLeft;

    useEffect(() => {
        const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            now = addSeconds(now, 1);
            setTimeLeft(intervalToDuration(now, endDate));
        }, 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(myInterval);
    }, []);

    return <div>{minutes} mins / {seconds} secs</div>
}
```

**test**

```
import MockDate from 'mockdate';

beforeEach(() => {
    MockDate.set(2022-12-24); // 24 hours before end date in code
    jest.useFakeTimers();
});

afterEach(() => {
    act(() => {
         jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    });

    jest.useRealTimers();
    MockDate.reset();
});

it.each([
   [/* minute data */],
   [/* hour data */],
   [/* day data */],
])('Should increment', (/* args from data above */) => {
   render(<ProductCardCountdown endDate={endDate}/>);

   // test before condition

   act(() => {
       jest.advanceTimersByTime(seconds * 1000); // seconds dictated by it.each data
   });

   // test after condition
});
```

In the past I have corrected memory leak issues by using the `return` on the `useEffect`, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call this `useEffect` only once, on mount, therefore just add an ampty array as a second parameter to your `useEffect`

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            now = addSeconds(now, 1);
            setTimeLeft(intervalBetweenDates(now, endDateFormatted));
        }, 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(myInterval);
    }, []);
```

If you don't put the empty array, the `useEffect` will be called at every render, which is to say every time `setTimeLeft` is called (state and props updates trigger re-renders), creating a huge number of `setInterval`s and thus the memory leaks.

Comment: Ah yes, apologies. I had done that between posting and now, but I still seem to be getting a memory leak. It appears to be caused by the actual `intervalToDuration` call for some reason.

Comment: And the `endDateFormatted` argument should be `endDate`, or is it declared somewhere else ?

Comment: Ah yes, apologies. Copy/paste issue. I have updated now.